# Swift - Execute group by and conditional sum

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to execute group by methods and conditional sum.

like :

```
    1. date:"22-04-2021", name: "morning", value: 2.5
    2. date:"22-05-2021", name: "morning", value: 3.6
    3. date:"22-04-2021", name: "morning", value: 5.9
    3. date:"22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 4.9
    5. date:"22-06-2021", name: "evening", value: 2.0
```

My final output will be group by date and sum all greater than 3 (value>3)

Here is my code. I tried little portion like grouping but did not meet in sum of this particular group.

```
struct model {
    var date : String?
    var name : String?
    var value : Double
}



func test(){
    
    var arrData = [model]()
    
    arrData.append(model(date: "22-04-2021", name: "morning", value: 2.5))
    arrData.append(model(date: "22-05-2021", name: "morning", value: 3.6))
    arrData.append(model(date: "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 5.9))
    arrData.append(model(date: "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 4.9))
    arrData.append(model(date: "22-06-2021", name: "evening", value: 2.0))

    let categorieNames = Array(Set(arrData.map({$0.date})))
    var arrResult:[[model]] = []
    for i in 0..<categorieNames.count {

        let categories :  [model] = arrData.filter({ $0.value > 3 && $0.date == categorieNames[i] })
 
        arrResult.append(categories)
    }

print(arrResult)
//            output like
//
//            [
//                ["22-04-2021", name: "morning", value: 2.5,
//                 "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 5.9,
//                 "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 4.9
//                ]
//
//                ["22-05-2021", name: "morning", value: 3.6],
//
//                ["22-06-2021", name: "evening", value: 2.0]
//            ]

}
```

Now I want to sum all group elements by applying a condition value greater than 3.

And final result will like this

```
[ "22-04-2021", name: "morning", value: 10.8,
  "22-05-2021", name: "morning", value: 3.6
]
```

Comment: What is the logic for `name`? At `22-04-2021` there are two different names in the group.

Comment: How do you "concat" `"22-04-2021", name: "morning", value: 2.5, "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 5.9,"22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 4.9`, I know the sum of the value, the date is the same, but what about `name`?

Comment: The name has no logic there. I will use the name property in data representation into view

Comment: @vadian. The name has no logic there. I will use the name property in data representation into view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all declare the struct with a capitalized name and non-optional (constant) members

```
struct Model {
    let date : String
    let name : String
    let value : Double
}
```

**Based on Joakim Danielson's answer** first `group` the array to a dictionary and get rid of the items with `value` <= 3

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: arrData.filter{ $0.value > 3}, by: { $0.date })
// -> ["22-04-2021": [Model(date: "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 5.9),        
//                    Model(date: "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 4.9)], 
//     "22-05-2021": [Model(date: "22-05-2021", name: "morning", value: 3.6)]]
```

Then `map` the dictionary to an array creating new `Model` instances and summing up the values

```
let result = grouped.map { item -> Model in
    let v = item.value.map{$0.value}.reduce(0.0, +)
    return Model(date: item.key, name: item.value.first!.name, value: v)
}
// -> [Model(date: "22-04-2021", name: "evening", value: 10.8), Model(date: "22-05-2021", name: "morning", value: 3.6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore the names you can use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` to group by date then followed by `mapValues` to calculate the sum. The filtering of values > 3 is actually done first when creating the dictionary

```
let result = Dictionary(grouping: arrData.filter({ $0.value > 3}), by: { $0.date })
   .mapValues({ $0.map(\.value).reduce(0, +)})
```

Comment: thank you. this answer partially helps to solve out.